# Duplicate _links key in CrudRepository REST response

Tags: spring-data-rest

Problem:
The CrudRepository return a faulty JSON Response with duplicate _links key

```
{"_links" : { },  
 "_embedded" : {
    "skills" : [ {
      "name" : "REST",
      "_links" : { }, <----------- Empty Links
      "_embedded" : { },
      "_links" : { <-------------- Usefull Links
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8081/api/skills/1",
          "templated" : false
        }
      }
    } ]   } }
```

Used Classes:
Repository:
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

```
public interface SkillRepository extends CrudRepository<Skill, Long> {}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Skill {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

}
```

If I include jackson-databind the problem occurs.

```
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of spring-hateoas includes jackson-databind 2.4.6.

In jackson-databind 2.6.0 `JsonSerialize.Inclusion` became deprecated; `JsonInclude` should be used instead. The Mixin classes from spring-hateoas (`ResourcesMixin`, `ResourceSupportMixin` & `LinkMixin`) use `JsonSerialize.Inclusion` which apparently is ignored.

**Solution**: use jackson-databind 2.5.4 (or lower) until the jackson version is updated in spring-hateoas.

Comment: The problem still persists in version 2.7.2 by the way